# Requesting a list from an API, populating <select> with all items on that list

Tags: javascript, json, fetch, es6-promise

I wasn't really sure how to work that title but, hello, I'm taking a JS course and at the end of one of the lecture there was an optional extra credit assignment:

> The dog.ceo API allows you to [request a list of breeds](https://dog.ceo/dog-api/documentation/). Use this list
> to populate a select field. Then when a user select a dog breed,
> show a picture of that dog using the [random image by breed](https://dog.ceo/dog-api/documentation/breed) API.

I've got the first half done, populating the select field with the breeds from the API but i've tried for hours to try to get the second part to work. On click, it should show a random image from that breed. I feel like i'm too close to give up on this, even if it's optional work. Any help would be greatly appreciated or even maybe a nudge in the right way

Demo

```js
const RANDOM_DOG = 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random';
const RANDOM_BREED = `https://dog.ceo/api/breed/hound/images/random`;
const BREED_LIST = 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all';
const dogBtn = document.querySelector('.get-doggo');
const dogDropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown');
const dogImages = document.querySelector('.images');
const loader = document.querySelector('.loader');

function randomDogPromise() {
    const promise = fetch(RANDOM_DOG);
    loader.classList.add('show'); // Showing our Loader Before new images load
    promise
        .then((response) => {
            const processedResponse = response.json();
            return processedResponse;
        })
        .then((data) => {
            loader.classList.remove('show'); // Hiding our Loader hter new images load

            // creating image element and appending them to the images div
            const img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = data.message;
            img.alt = 'Cute Doggos';
            img.width = 300;
            dogImages.appendChild(img);
        });
}

function populateDropdownList() {
    const promise = fetch(BREED_LIST);
    promise
        .then((response) => {
            const processedResponse = response.json();
            return processedResponse;
        })
        .then((data) => {
            const breedList = Object.keys(data.message);
            breedList.map((breed) => {
                const option = document.createElement('option');
                option.value = breed;
                option.innerText = breed;
                dogDropdown.appendChild(option);
            });
        });
}

window.addEventListener('click', populateDropdownList());
dogBtn.addEventListener('click', randomDogPromise);
```

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande',
        'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: #f3e9c5;
}

.doggos {
    width: 90%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.doggos .controls {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.doggos .controls div {
    flex: 1;
}

.doggos .controls .dropdown {
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

.doggos .controls button {
    border: none;
    margin: 0 20px;
    width: 90%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #d7503e;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #b0b0b0;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 0px 40px;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}

.doggos button:hover {
    background-color: #ab3b2c;
}

.doggos .images {
    margin-top: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.doggos .images img {
    border: 2px solid #f3e9c5;
    flex: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

.loader-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.loader {
    display: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.show {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="doggos">
    <div class="controls">
      <div class="half">
        <button class="get-doggo">Click for doggo</button>
      </div>
      <div class="half">
        <select class="dropdown" name="" id="">
          <option selected disabled>Choose Your Random Doggo</option>

        </select>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="loader-wrapper">
      <img class="loader" src="200.gif" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="images">

    </div>

  </div>
```

Comment: What you need, is a listener on `change` event on the select dropdown.